# Moodle Error: database driver problem detected

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I Have installed Moodle Version MOODLE_39_STABLE following the original documentation:  https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Step-by-step_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu
During the installation of Moodle, I am facing the issue

> Error: database driver problem detected.The site administrator should
> verify the server configuration PHP has not been properly configured
> with the MySQLi extension for it to communicate with MySQL. Please
> check your php.ini file or recompile PHP.

I have gone through several forums, StackOverflow tasks enabled php7.4_mysql extension uncommented the extension=mysqlnd.so in my php.ini file restarted the apache server but there is no use.

Please let me know what exactly I am doing wrong.

Server: Ubuntu 18.04
Web server: Apache2
Php : Php 7.4
Moodle Version: Moodle 39_stable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have mysql extension installed and you need mysql**i** (i stands for improved) extension: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score -1):

**You may be missing `lib\dml\mysqli_native_moodle_database.php`**

It happened to me when upgrading moodle from 3.9 to 4.1.5 and there are a couple of files you could be missing while doing the upgrade or changing git branches in between branchs for differents moodles versions.